# TYPO3 site properties do not appear

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-7.6.x

In Typo3 (I am extremely new to it) I just set up a new installation. Under Template I inserted a few lines of TypoScript (which works) into a template on the "Home"-page in the tree.

Now, in the "Sites"-mode, I added some pages to the "Home"-page. When I click

- on a page in this mode,
- on the edit icon in list mode for a specific site in tree

the right side appears grey where normally I should see some properties.

[image: typo3 backend]

The installation is installed by the hoster. Why is it?

Comment: Check the requests that TYPO3 does when clicking that page (Firebug, Developer tools, or similar). They probably fail, and maybe you can determine the reason. Also, go into the install tool and put the site in development mode, which should give you much better error messages/stack traces.

Comment: edit file /typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php and enable display errors to see what exactly problem there: return [ 'SYS' => [ 'displayErrors' => 1 ] ];

Comment: It turned out, that there is not enough memory for TYPO3 7 on this server. Is there a way to reduce the need of memory?

Comment: To which value is `memory_limit` set on your server? 64MB are the minimum (for TYPO3 6.2 and upwards). Depending on your hoster, you can increase it yourself. If not, you'll probably have to upgrade your hosting package (or if they promised that TYPO3 will run on the current one, ask your money back).